# can i use again a function that wraps setInterval and clearInterval statements?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, clearinterval

i have a following function:

```
const catchingEggs = () => { 
    let eggIndex;
    document.querySelector('html').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    leftArrow.style.display = 'none';
    rightArrow.style.display = 'none';
    player.removeEventListener('click', catchingEggs);
    leftArrow.removeEventListener('click', choosePlayerLeft);
    rightArrow.removeEventListener('click', choosePlayerRight);
    document.querySelector('html').requestFullscreen();
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){  
        if(score % 10 === 0) {
            speed -= 10;
            intervalScore += 5
        }
        if(heartIndex < 0) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return;    
        }
        eggIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*4); 
        fallingEggs(allEggs[eggIndex], speed);
        }, intervalLength); 
}
```

which works fine, but if i want to keep reusing this function after `clearInterval` happened, by adding another `catchingEggs()` to the main function:

```
const playGame = () => { 
    screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
    document.querySelector('html').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(31, 28, 28)';
    playerImages[0].style.display = 'block';
    player.addEventListener('click', catchingEggs);
    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', choosePlayerRight); 
    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', choosePlayerLeft);
}
```

to execute after a conditional, it doesn't do anything. Ideally i'd like to be able to change `intervalLength` while inside the interval, but that doesn't seem to be possible, so at least i want to be able to go around it by initiating the whole thing again, for example when `score >= 20`, so i added a new variable when true, as a condition of `clearInterval` (so far so good), and then inside `playGame()`: if new variable true `catchingEggs()`, but nothing happened.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `heartIndex` is external to this example, and so two calls to `catchingEggs` may very well experience the same termination condition (at which `clearInterval` is called).  Not sure if that's what you intend or not.

Comment: yeah, that's intentional, `heartIndex`  are lives, so the lives you kept in first interval are carried to the next and if you're down to 0 then its `clearInterval` and you don't have enough `score` to start another interval.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you could create a minimal reproducible example using the stack snippet editor that highlights how "nothing happened" when you were expecting something to happen.